# How to find out the current url visited in marshmallow?

Tags: android

In api 23 ,entire bookmark is been removed ,so is there any way i can get the latest url visited by the user.Is it possible or not?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean ? What do you mean by "Entire bookmark" ? Is the user visiting the URL using the browser or with your app ?

Comment: I was trying to know current url  accessed from my android app, for doing so, we were using bookmark to get the browser history,so that I can get the current url accessed ,but in api 23,marshmallow it is deprecated for security reasons.

Comment: You would need root for that, and then read the history / bookmarks directly from the database file. That means that the device your app is running on would need to be rooted.

Comment: ya but I don't want my device to be rooted

Comment: I don't think there's any other way, unfortunately.

Comment: one solution I found is to use netstat command on adb shell, but don't know whether it is supported on all the versions.

Comment: Netstat would not give you information on what other apps are doing either, if you don't have root. (I believe)